# One-off token feature needed

Tags: quire-api

Trying to create some custom behavior with Zapier, and the app framework just doesn't fit. All I need is a one-off token to paste into my Zap. Can you add like a "generate new token" feature on projects and organizations, please?

Answer (score 0):

Authorization with for the QuireAPI is based on the OAuth2 standard.
From the [related docs](https://platform.zapier.com/docs/oauth) it looks like Zapier supports this as well.

Please consider using the more flexible Oauth2 flow over a "convenient" on-off-token.

**UPDATE**: new feature discussed in [quire-api#26](https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/26)